# determine the error bound for the interpolation error at $x = \frac{\pi}{4}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have been able to derive the interpolation polynomial $P_2(x)$ of degree two which interpolates $f(x) = \sin x$, given the points $(0,0), \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, 1\right), (\pi, 0).$

Solution:
$$P_2(x) = \frac{4}{\pi ^2}x(\pi - x)$$

**Here is the question below I am having trouble with**

> Calculate $P_2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, an approximation for $f\left( \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$ and determine the error bound for the interpolation error at $x = \frac{\pi}{4}.$

Calculating  $P_2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

$$P_2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{4}{\pi ^2} \times \frac{\pi}{4}\left( \pi - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)=  \frac{3}{4}$$

If we plug $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ into $f(x) = \sin x$ we get $f(\pi /4) = \sin (\pi /4) \approx 0.7071 $

**Here is my attempt below at finding the error bound**

Writing the error as $err(x) = \sin x - P_2(x) = \sin x - \frac{4}{\pi ^2}x(\pi - x)$

Differentiating once gives,

$$\cos (x) - \frac{4(\pi - 2x)}{\pi ^2}$$

Differentiating twice gives,

$$\frac{8}{\pi ^2}-\sin(x)$$

Finally differentiating a third time gives,

$$- \cos x $$

**But how do I use this to get my error bound**

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error

Comment: I have been trying but I dont understand how to do it. Could you make a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a polynomial interpolation of order $n$, the maximum error is given by
$${\rm err}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\max |f^{(n+1)}(x)|\max|\prod_{p=0}^n(x-x_p)|$$
Here $x_p$ are the roots of your polynomial.
Let's suppose that you are interested in finding the maximum only in the interval from $0$ to $\pi$.
The maximum of the derivative in your case is $1$, the maximum for the product $x(\pi-x)$ occurs at $\pi/2$ so $${\rm err}=\frac{1}{3!}1\left(\frac\pi2\right)^2$$

Comment: Is this the complete solution? And why only in that interval?

Comment: Outside of the interval the product will increase. Say at very large $x$, the product part is approximately $-x^2$. That means that the error in your interpolation is very large. You can see this by plotting the two curves, say from $0$ to $10$

Comment: Okay and I'm only worried about my interval. Why is $\pi /2 $ squared?

Comment: Plug in $x=\pi/2$ in $x(\pi-x)$

Comment: Okay and the max is 1 because when we plug in $0,\pi /2, \pi$ into our third derivative which is $-cosx$ the max value is 1?

Comment: It can be any point in that interval. Even if you were given $x=0.1,0.3,3$, still $\max\cos x=1$ for any large enough interval

Comment: And also was my calculating for $P_2(\pi /4$ correct? Just simply plugging it into $P_2(x)$

Comment: Yes. It looks fine to me

Comment: Thanks I understand the process now!

Comment: do I need to include the calculation of the derivatives in your answer?

Comment: No. Just for the function.